# How to send data as hotspot device using UDP (flutter)

Tags: flutter, udp

I'm trying to make an application that would send data between devices using local network. One device has to create a hotspot, so that everyone on the network could send and receive data between devices.

Currently I have the code that does exactly this, for all the devices connected to the hotspot:

```
  var multicastEndpoint = Endpoint.multicast(
    InternetAddress('239.1.1.1'),
    port: Port(54321),
  );

  void listenForMessages() async {
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(
      content: Text("Listening..."),
    ));

    // receiving\listening
    var receiver = await UDP.bind(multicastEndpoint);

    receiver.asStream().listen((datagram) {
      if (datagram != null) {
        var str = String.fromCharCodes(datagram.data);
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
          content: Text(str),
        ));
      }
    });
  }

  void sendMessage(String msg) async {
    var sender = await UDP.bind(Endpoint.any());

    var bytesSent = await sender.send(msg.codeUnits, multicastEndpoint);

    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
      content: Text("Sent $bytesSent bytes"),
    ));
  }
```

But the problem arises when I try to send a message from the hotspot device - other devices receive nothing, but it shows that some bytes are being sent. The host device receives nothing as well.